# How doubles truncate in swift in case of overflow

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

I know that swift's Double values have 15 decimal point precision so I took a variable

```
let pi: Double = 3.1415926535897932384
```

and REPL returned me

```
pi: Double = 3.1415926535897931
```

One thing I can clearly see that REPL has rounded off 32384 to 31(in case of overflow). So, is it following the standard mathematics rule for rounding off or something else.

Comment: That's not called overflow, it's just a floating point rounding error. Generally only 15 digits can be preserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has to do how floating point digits are represented in binary. So the conversion to binary doesn't round to the next decimal representation instead it converts it to the next binary one.

```
// test this in a playground
9.05 // returns 9.050000000000001
```

You shouldn't consider the last digit of a double value in general.